# Matrix equation power problem

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$, $B$ two square matrix such as $I-A$ and $I+B$ are similar.
prove that $A^2$ and $B^2$ are similar.

This is my answer , and I'm not entirely sure that its the way to solve it.

from the question, we know that there is a reverse matrix $P$ such as: $P^{-1}(I+B)P = I-A$.

then $P^{-1}IP + P^{-1}BP = I - A$ then $P^{-1}BP = -A$.

$P^{-1}B^2P = (P^{-1}BP)(P^{-1}BP) = (-A)(-A) = A^2$

is that how you solve this kind of questions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your reasoning is correct. Your initial requirement of $I-A$ and $I+B$ being similar is just a convoluted way to say that $-A$ and $B$ are similar.

I wouldn't call $P$ reverse matrix, but inverible matrix, though.